# Unexpected Result - Using IF() to get text data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using `IF()` formula to compare two fields (numbers), and getting the name (text) corresponding to that number.

I'm getting an error where the name(text) is only picked up, if the compared fields (number) are in the same row number.

[image: Image displaying results]

Formula used: `=IF(F:F = B13, G:G,"nope")`

**Edit** : Solved
Used formula `=VLOOKUP(B13,F:G,2,0)`

Comment: Look like an index() with match() would work better.

Comment: Have you considered a `VLOOKUP`?

Comment: I looked it up just now. It works! thanks 

formula :: **=VLOOKUP(B13,F:G,2,0)**

Comment: Using `=VLOOKUP(B13,F:G,2,0)` you refer to the whole columns which may cause delays. You could select the exact range. More over, what will be happen if you search for value `2` and your range has more than one `2`? Additionally, in your formula you use only one fields and your question you mention 2.

Comment: To deal with errors you could look at =iferror(VLOOKUP(B13,F:G,2,0),"error")

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks! I had some errors I had to deal with, this helps

Comment: @Error1004 In the actual data there is only one number to one  text name. I did think about using exact range, but my actual data is quite big, and could increase in the future - hence I'm using the whole columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question was marked as unanswered hence Answering behalf of **Solar Mike** and **user2690474**

Use "=VLOOKUP(B13,F:G,2,0)"

To deal with errors you could look at =iferror(VLOOKUP(B13,F:G,2,0),"error")